# display view after draw gui

Tags: iphone

I have an app that take a long time to draw gui components on a view.
I prefer to display the view after the task of drawing gui components is completed.
It looks like that I need get the trigger event when all component have been put on the view. 
Is it possible? or there is any other solution?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to figure out why it takes so long - mostly it shouldn't.  The drawing code is generally going to check and not draw what isn't visible so when you make it visible it'll actually draw everything, so I'm not sure if what you are trying to do is really going to solve your problem.  I'd figure out why it's taking so long.

Could try Set the view.hidden = YES, add stuff to the view, then set view.hidden = NO;

Comment: I draw 100 buttons on the view, 'set view.hidden = NO' I need to get the event that 100 buttons have been put on the view, but I do not know how to do

Comment: What puts the buttons into the view?  Are you doing this manually in code or are you doing this using IB?